# Load Child Views into IFrame with Zend Framework Application

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I have a client-side html and javascript application that uses a REST API, that returns JSON. Right now I have the main page when you login, store profile information in a javascript object. Then all other pages in the system are displayed in an iFrame, so that they can access the JSON data in the parent page, without making another ajax call.

I need to move the appliation to Zend Framework, due to future requirements, and I'm not sure how to render a single view, that contains an iframe, and then load all other views into it, instead of instantiating a new layout template and just loading the view.

I know enough about Zend Framework to get started, so I'm not looking for basic Zend Framework help, just a crazy use case, why an iframe...I don't know, client requirements.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your default layout to be the one used in iframes (ie, minimal decoration)

   ```
   ; application.ini

   resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
   resources.layout.layout = "iframe"
   ; refers to application/layouts/scripts/iframe.phtml
   ```
2. In your main page controller, set the layout to be the full page version

   ```
   public function indexAction() {
       $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('full');
       // refers to application/layouts/scripts/full.phtml
   }
   ```
3. In your full page layout, create your iframe and name it

   ```
       <iframe src="" name="content" height="100" width="200">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
   ```
4. In your main page view, direct links to open in the iframe

   ```
   <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
       'action' => 'some-action'
   )) ?>" target="content">Click me</a>
   ```

Comment: I will try it and see if it works...Thanks :) Will mark as answer if it works...Trying now.